# Python: How to impute the missing value in a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, imputation

I have CSV data that has to be analyzed with Python. The data has some missing values in it. the sample of the data is given as follows:

**SAMPLE**

```
ID,ID_TYPE,OB_DATE,VERSION_NUM,MET_DOMAIN_NAME,OB_END_CTIME,OB_DAY_CNT,SRC_ID,REC_ST_IND,PRCP_AMT,OB_DAY_CNT_Q,PRCP_AMT_Q,METO_STMP_TIME,MIDAS_STMP_ETIME,PRCP_AMT_J
90, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,1, WADRAIN,900,1,24109,1011,0,0,6, 2006-01-17 09:04,0,
150, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,1, DLY3208,900,1,30747,1011,0,0,6, 2006-01-09 13:21,3,
174, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,1, WADRAIN,900,1,24775,1011,0.2,0,6, 2006-01-17 09:04,0,
498, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,0, WADRAIN,900,1,1622,1012,0.1,0,1, 2006-01-17 09:04,0,
498, RAIN,,1, WADRAIN,900,31,1622,1022,58.3,0,22576, 2006-03-15 11:41,0,
898, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,0, WADRAIN,900,6,1624,1012,18.5,0,20001,,0,
898, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,1, WADRAIN,900,1,1624,1022,0.4,0,2576, 2006-03-15 11:41,0,
996, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,1, WAMRAIN,900,31,24953,1011,53.5,0,6, 2006-01-31 13:51,0,
997, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,1, WADRAIN,900,1,24953,1011,1.6,0,6, 2006-02-02 12:28,0,
1045, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,1, WADRAIN,900,1,1628,1011,1.1,0,6, 2006-01-17 09:04,0,
1103, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,1, WADRAIN,900,1,24772,1011,2.5,0,6, 2006-01-17 09:04,0,
1358, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,0, WADRAIN,900,11,1633,1012,17.7,0,20001,,0,
1358, RAIN,,1, WADRAIN,900,31,1633,1022,42.5,0,22576, 2006-03-15 11:41,0,
1545, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,1, WADRAIN,900,1,1636,1011,2,0,6, 2006-01-17 09:04,0,
1584, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,1, WADRAIN,900,1,315,1014,2.4,0,2306, 2006-03-15 11:41,0,
1858, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,1, WADRAIN,900,1,1645,1011,0.2,0,6, 2006-01-17 09:04,0,
2247, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,1, WADRAIN,900,1,24781,1011,0.5,0,6, 2006-01-17 09:04,0,
3066, RAIN,,1, WADRAIN,900,1,1655,1011,0.6,0,6, 2006-02-02 12:28,0,
3067, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,0, WADRAIN,900,7,1655,1012,11,0,20001, 2006-01-26 15:08,0,
3067, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,1, WADRAIN,900,31,1655,1022,57.5,0,22576, 2006-03-15 11:41,0,
3507, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,0, WADRAIN,900,2,1657,1012,15.8,0,20001,,0,
3507, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,1, WADRAIN,900,1,1657,1022,0.9,0,2576, 2006-04-13 13:28,0,
4802, RAIN,,0, WADRAIN,900,6,1663,1012,18,0,20001, 2006-01-17 09:04,0,
4802, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,1, WADRAIN,900,1,1663,1022,0.9,0,2576, 2006-03-15 11:41,0,
4941, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,1, WADRAIN,900,1,1664,1011,0.5,0,6, 2006-01-17 09:04,1,
4942, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,1, WADRAIN,900,1,1664,1011,1.2,0,6, 2006-02-02 12:28,0,
```

The data has some missing `OB_DATE` and `METO_STMP_TIME`, and I want to impute the missing values in these fields.

The basic questions here are:

1. What are the imputing of missing values and what are the ways in which we could do it?

I Googled a lot for this and I was not clear with the concept of imputation.

2. How can we do it in Python without using any external libraries?

If external libraries are used then it is fine, but is their a possible way to do it without any external libraries.

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html

Comment: @PaulH i am still not getting answers for point 1.

Comment: What do you want to "impute" the missing values with? You'll forsure need at the bare minimum the `csv` library.

Comment: That documentation covers interpolation, forward/backward filling, substitution, etc.

Comment: i meant to say external libraries. like `pandas` etc. @thefoxrocks i know i will be using CSV module. and firstly i need to know what is imputation, how it is done, ways of imputation etc. then i will go for how to do it in my problem.

Comment: @PaulH is right were `Pandas` will work for this, but it is obviously an external library. If not, you'll have to cycle over each row and fill in missing values on some condition.

Comment: @desmond.carros if all you type into google is the word "imputation", you get a definition. Perhaps you need to clarify you're question.

Comment: imputation is substitution of data. I am searching for the ways of imputation. I have read about `mean,median,mode` substitution but i am sure there are other ways too. And i don't know where will the `mean` imputation method work, where `mode` will work and where `median` will work. all and all i need a basic tutorial or any documentation for that. @PaulH

Comment: That's not a programming question. SO is for specific, reproducible programming problems.

Comment: @PaulH so what do you think, how should i quote my problem here? i just got stuck with this and i am just hitting links around Google but not getting any concrete results for my questions. Please help!

Comment: This is very open-ended statistics question. Try searching stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score -1):

I AM A BEGINNER, I HOPE IT HELPS!

```
import pandas as pd
dataset=pd.read_csv('filename/path')
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imputer=Imputer(missing_values='Nan',strategy='mean',axis=0)
X=dataset.iloc[:,2].values
Y=dataset.iloc[:,-3].values
#lets do second column first
imputer=imputer.fit(X[:,2])
X[:,2]=imputer.transform(X[:,2])
# third last column
imputer=imputer.fit(Y[:,-3])
Y[:,-3]=imputer.transform(Y[:,-3])
```